# How to get the return value of a Java method using Frida

Tags: android, python, frida

TLDR i am looking to use Frida to call an unused method in an Android app and get back its value. Currently, I am not getting any return in my scripts output.

Code for the Android app:

```
package securisec.com.methods;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public static String strings(){
        return "This is a string method";
    }

}
```

As you can see, the `strings` method is never used. I want to be able to call this method using Frida and get the return value back.

Here is my python script that is not working.

```
import frida
from time import sleep

call_back_message = ''

def on_message(message, payload):
    global call_back_message
    if message['type'] == 'send':
        call_back_message = message['payload']
        return call_back_message

def object_hooking(comName, className, method):
    process = frida.get_usb_device()
    pid = process.spawn([comName])
    process.resume(pid)
    sleep(1)
    js = """
            Java.perform(function()
            {
                var getVal = Java.use('%s.%s');
                console.log(getVal)
                var cons = getVal.$new();
                console.log(cons)
                var solution = cons.%s;
                var send_it = solution.toString();
                send(send_it);
            });""" % (comName, className, method)
    session = process.attach(pid)
    script = session.create_script(js)
    script.on('message', on_message)
    script.load()
    return call_back_message

print(object_hooking(
    comName='securisec.com.methods', 
    className='MainActivity',
    method='strings()'
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to create new instance, you got couple of typo's but overall it seems you get the point.

If the method exists in

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Java.use('securisec.com.methods.MainActivity').__proto__).join('\n\t')
```

and the compiler did not exclude it, the following code should do the work

```
def main():
    device = frida.get_usb_device()
    script = device.attach(device.spawn([APP])).create_script("""
        Java.perform(function(){
            console.log( 
                Java.use('securisec.com.methods.MainActivity')['strings']() 
            );
        });
    """)
    script.load()
    device.resume(APP)
    sys.stdin.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I prefer to keep clean style :)

```
function Main() {
    var retVal = Java.use("securisec.com.methods.MainActivity")["strings"]();
    console.log("retVal", retVal);
}
Java.perform(Main);
```

You can also test w/ REPL

```
$ frida -U com.app -e 'console.log(Java.use("securisec.com.methods.MainActivity")["strings"]())' --no-pause
```